# What parameters can I pass to `gradle dependencies`

Tags: gradle, dependencies

When I run `gradle dependencies`, I can show the dependency tree of a gradle project. Is there any parameter I can pass?

I know just one `--configuration compile` from somewhere, but can't find any documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gradle dependencies` is a [DependencyReportTask](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask.html) task. Checking [Gradle source code for this task](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/diagnostics/DependencyReportTask.java) it looks like the `configuration` is the only option for this task (the only one decorated with the [@Option](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/options/Option.java) annotation), i.e:

> ```
> @Option(option = "configuration", description = "The configuration to generate the report for.")
> public void setConfiguration(String configurationName) {
>     this.configurations = Collections.singleton(getProject().getConfigurations().getByName(configurationName));
> }
> ```